# NSdate Formatter and result convert to NSstring

Tags: ios, nsdate

want to ask about NSDate Formatter

i want to create Date and time like that

> Friday, 12 June 2013

my code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

output=

> Saturday

does anyone know how to create date like above and convert it to nsstring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to show that string to the user? If so set the `dateStyle` because you want a locale aware string.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Users that use the US locale will get `Saturday, November 24, 2012`.
And german users will get `Samstag, 24. November 2012`.

Comment: hi matthias you're right... but i've found the best answer 2 minutes ago

here's my code=[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE,MMMM dd yyyy"];